# CSS3 columns - change the way they position content

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have two columns which are created using CSS3 Columns. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="column1">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>

    <div class="column2">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

All is good so far. However, the way the browser creates the columns is a problem for me. Because it creates them to be equal height, some of the content from `.column1` has been shifted into `.column2`, at the top. Instead of being at the top of `.column2`, I want it at the bottom. Here is an image to visualise what I mean:

[image: current layout vs desired layout]

What would I do to shift the content at the top of `.column2` (from `.column1`) to the bottom of `.column2`? (I cannot move the HTML code, although it's fine to change the CSS so it's not using columns or whatever).

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your current layout please?

Comment: Don't see **any** way you could get the first column to wrap that way..if that is, in fact, what you are expecting. That's not what the column layout is for.

Comment: If you are using CSS columns, you should not be using divs to create columns as well. It should be one way or the other.

Comment: sounds like you might want to be using flex-box: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/